# Implement undo and redo functions using a stack. How to edit a stack without having to recreate it in Haskell

Tags: haskell, stack, undo, redo

I have a custom datatype called TextFile which stores four strings and I need to be able to store a version of it in a stack each time the text file is edited. This is so that I can implement some form of Undo and redo function.

However, the stack will be updated from within other functions and without creating a new stack each time, I can't see a way to save the changes when I push something to it?

Is there a way that I could create a stack and update that same stack each time something is pushed or popped from it?

```
newtype Stack a = Stack [a] deriving (Eq, Show)
buffer = Stack [] :: Stack TextFile

data TextFile = TextFile String String String String deriving Show
file = TextFile "This is the left element" " This is the right element" "" ""

pop :: Stack a -> (Maybe a, Stack a)
pop (Stack (x:xs)) = (Just x, Stack xs)
pop (Stack []) = (Nothing, Stack [])

push :: a -> Stack a -> Stack a
push x (Stack xs) = Stack (x:xs)
```

To clarify, my main question is if you can't change a variable's value in Haskell, how do you create a stack as a structure without duplicating it?

Comment: this is a classic use case for the State monad, which you can find lots of references for online. Eg. here in [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#state) for a very gentle introduction (there's even an exxample of modelling a stack with `push` and `pop` methods, like yours). You need to understand the basics of monads first though.

Comment: What's the difference between creating a new stack with changes and throwing away the old one, vs. changing the old one? Lookup mutable vs immutable data structures. You may still want help here, in which case you should provide more detail about the precise problem you're encountering (eg. a function that you can't make it do exactly what you want). In general though - try just creating a new one! It won't hurt (trust me)~

Comment: To expand on my comment and link it to that of @ATayler - you can certainly do it his way, but it can get quite tedious manually writing the code to thread the state through every function you write. And this is what the State monad is for, it just allows you to write clearer code by hiding all that boilerplate "under the hood" (in the implementation of the State monad itself). It doesn't do any "magic" that you can't do without it.

Comment: Ah nice one, I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Robin is totally right - just personally I find a good way to learn about eg. the state monad is to go through the rigmarole of writing the boilerplate yourself a few times before wondering, "is there a way to abstract cleanly over all this?" And only then can you appreciate the beauty of the solution! (YMMV).

Comment: Also, note that there is a difference between *you* duplicating a stack and the *compiler* actually copying a data structure in memory. *Because* values are immutable, the compiler can let `Stack xs` and `Stack (x:xs)` both share a reference to `xs` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how do you create a stack as a structure without duplicating it?

The code you have presented is fine and will not duplicate much data.

Let's say you have a current stack of `stack1 = a - b - c - d - e`.  And now you `pop stack1` with the code:

```
pop (Stack (x:xs)) = (Just x, Stack xs)
```

You will return a new stack `stack2 = b - c - d - e` which is just the entire structure after the `a` and nothing is copied.  If you keep stack1 around then you'd have two structures that look something like this:

```
 stack1 -> a - b - c - d - e
               ^
               |
             stack2
```

Bear in mind the singly linked list you're using means `a` is not part of `stack2`.  If `stack1` is garbage collected then you'll end up with `stack2 = b -  c - d - e` as you'd expect.

Now let's say you `push z stack2` yielding `stack3 = z - b - c - d - e`.  If `stack1` and `stack2` are still live then the heap would look something like:

```
     stack3 -> z
               |
 stack1 -> a - b - c - d - e
               ^
               |
             stack2
```